# Как поменять местами минимальный и последний нулевой элементы массива А?

Tags: c++, массивы

Как найти последний нулевой элемент и поменять местами с минимальным?

Записал массив и нахождение минимального элемента:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int N;
    cout << "Введите размер массива:" << endl;
    cout << "N = ";
    cin >> N;
    double* A = new double[N];
    cout << "Введите массив:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    cout << "Массив до преобразования: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "["<< i + 1 << "]: " << A[i] << endl;

    }

    cout << "Массив после преобразования: " << endl;

    int Min = A[0];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] < Min)
        {
            Min = A[i];
        }
    }
    
    cout << Min << endl;

    system("pause > void");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код:

```
int sym[] = { 0 };
int arr[] = { 1, 0, 2, -1, 0, 3, 0, 7, 1 };

std::iter_swap(
    std::min_element(arr, arr + std::size(arr)),
    std::find_end(arr, arr + std::size(arr), sym, sym + 1));
```

Вывод:

```
1 0 2 -1 0 3  0 7 1 // До
1 0 2  0 0 3 -1 7 1 // После
```

Проверку не добавлял, но её обязателно надо сделать, а именно:

- проверить, не является ли массив пустым
- есть ли среди элементов массива нулевой, в принципе

Comment: Ну если уж вы работаете на С++, то и брали бы вместо `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)` просто `size(arr)`...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо! :) Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Лучше просто `std::find` с нулём и реверсивными итераторами использовать, чем делать массив из одного элемента

Comment: @dIm0n, пожалуйста, добавьте новый ответ.

Comment: @isnullxbh ваш ответ уже отвечает на вопрос, так что не вижу смысла давать новый, отличающийся одной строчкой. Я просто дополнил, чтобы будущие читатели видели, как можно сделать очевиднее

Comment: @dIm0n, на мой взгляд - ничего страшного в этом нет, как раз по той причине, которую Вы указали. Но, разумеется, дело Ваше.

Answer (score 0):

нахождение индекса последнего нулевого элемента

```
  const int size = 10;
  int array[size] = { 0,1,2,3,4,0,5,7,0,8 }; 

  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0;i < size;++i) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
      index = i;
    }
  }
```